# Swift parse URI from card with regex

Tags: regex

I need get URI of photo. URI spans multiple lines with delimiters. What should be the right side of the pattern to capture everything up to the uppercase letters with a colon? Such as END:, FN: or N:?

```
let pattern = "URI:(.*)"
let text = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\nPRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iPhone OS 13.6//EN\r\nN:;John;;;\r\nFN:John\r\nTEL;TYPE=CELL,VOICE,pref:+71234567890\r\nPHOTO;VALUE=URI:https://imgurl.com/download/photo.2A2472\r\n 0C-745E-4B17-AE46-B575B81C9490.afeb521a-9397-484a-8703-3e246b6d526d.19D320\r\n 9E-EC79-48D5-AE65-0E29CF208278\r\nEND:VCARD"
```

Expected Result is **[https://imgurl.com/download/photo.2A2472\r\n0C-745E-4B17-AE46-B575B81C9490.afeb521a-9397-484a-8703-3e246b6d526d.19D320\r\n9E-EC79-48D5-AE65-0E29CF208278\r\n](https://imgurl.com/download/photo.2A2472%5Cr%5Cn0C-745E-4B17-AE46-B575B81C9490.afeb521a-9397-484a-8703-3e246b6d526d.19D320%5Cr%5Cn9E-EC79-48D5-AE65-0E29CF208278%5Cr%5Cn)**

Comment: You can make the dot match a newline `URI(.*?)(?:END|F?N):` https://regex101.com/r/AC802F/1

Comment: What do you want to do, what is your expected end result?

Comment: Thanks, but END: or FN: is example, I want parse URI to any capital letter and :

Comment: @PavelSinkevich Then use `URI(.*?)[A-Z]+:` https://regex101.com/r/hd9C2i/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
(?s)URI(.*?)\s*[A-Z]+:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6MniY/1) | [Swift demo code](https://tio.run/##TVJbb9owFH73r3DpS9IS50IuJKyauLgbE4MKWqSN8WCIgUjBjmxnbTX1tzMngQ0/RLbzXXy@c@RrtlP@6ZQdCy4UfOQlS4nKOAMgpwoWRCkqGHyAty3jszRf5mMD3X02f8m7Vd/6ub5PWrc1UNA9fdMwJd5v4HQxp/syJwK/FYJKqeWMs1JykWxDXlQ@MoErRNj2wIX8TtT2MMkYlW2IUq7qM5XVzYIWRBClQWuzNlRUqoUSGdvXj2u1wAB/GU@T5bA/H4Elni/Gs2nSQQ54ms9G41Fi2Xa/KHIKx2yLbDt7OnBG4WwB3Q4KbRtPwTTpfeMH1uv1wOM0qbbgGU96zz@e8MMQTybt5Ww8xG1d0i65j1yv4wdh1I21w9fZ86y37E9e8INOKDkoVchEexz3pcjRlh/tlL@ynJPULg5cceT1PT/yAHSGVuQH2PIHbmT1sR9agyAKBl13GPuxg8iObgLPJVbciSPL7/rE6kZOx@pQzw83YRp4YYrceNTxHABjbOFhFGvYKNBaYWA52IuHj57T9aIuwNPRORyg02q6JusA54TtqU5Rt63aGTnf1iOQQKcNc8r26pBc5Y1KtXNDXVXJVNOLY9MnLVGPATqfjYxd89pQVPLJtasJfhOhWbLMlR6EVYNcr7XUag12XDTaMGP/TP4AqFdF2wteFtX8nFkNqfpbEWuzMUv1WGq2CxH61GggVh43VMx29QsugtVqBBEpCspSw7gaMSJ1Os3eRLLcNCUYr1kVTaNa@xlEl/Hf2TTNWvyj/mY7eHO2yCQ@Fur9yrvJ4OLdwC7kD1BoO2U0GPN0@gs)

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, make the dot match a newline
- `URI` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match any char, as least chars as possible
- `\s*[A-Z]+:` Match 0+ whitespace chars, 1+ uppercase chars A-Z followed by `:`

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

`https?:.*(?=END)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E8S6VO/1) in PCRE